# Jenkins setup wizard behind a proxy

Tags: jenkins

I installed Jenkins on my local machine and during the setup wizard I need to set the proxy up. After entering my proxy data, I checked to see if the `https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json` URL works, and it doesn't. I get the error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:516)

    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.verifyHostName(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:257)

    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:200)
...
```

I tried the HTTP site and that one worked, but after I saved the wizard still says I'm offline and I can't install plugins. What's going on?